# Does Queue services like Kafka, Amazon SQS use some datastore to store messages?

Tags: message-queue, amazon-sqs

Do you know how does any queue services work behind the scenes? Do they store the messages in some datastore? Eg. Amazon SQS keeps the messages in its queue until any workers pulls those messages from SQS.

Where does it store behind the scenes? I think in some data store like Dynamodb or RDS. Is that correct to say? Are there any resources which can give me more insight on how the design of general Queue service looks like?

Comment: This is likely pretty proprietary to Amazon.  SQS existed years before DynamoDB or RDS so at least originally there was something else behind it.  In general there is likely to be some sort of persistent store behind a queue but it could be as simple as a file.  And AWS could change it tomorrow and it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I designed the SQS replicated datastore. It was a completely custom implementation tailored for messaging use cases. Relational databases are not a good fit for high throughput queues.

Unfortunately, I cannot share the details of the datastore or replication algorithm as it was never made public by Amazon.

Kafka is open source, so you can get information about its [store design](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/design.html).